# web.config error

Tags: asp.net, configuration, web-config, connection-string

i am trying to deploy my website to my host and get following error message on my web. config file:

> The configuration section
>   'connectionStrings' cannot be read
>   because it is missing a section
>   declaration
>
> at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage
>   message, WebResponse response, Stream
>   responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)  at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
>   methodName, Object[] parameters)

the connectionstring is declared as follows:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="ConnectionStrings.config"/>
```

and in corresponding connectionStrings.config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="" connectionString="Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=dataSource;Initial Catalog=databaseName;User Id=userName;Password=password;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;Connect Timeout=120" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The web.config file is not encrypted and I am at a loss

Comment: @Nissim - I've fixed the formatting, declarations are now visible.

Answer (score 3):

If your application is configured to run with the .NET framework 1.1 but you developed it for .NET Framework 2.0 (or higher) the web.config file is different and has this "connectionStrings" XML node.

You should check the configuration of your site in the Internet Information Server. Right click on the website, choose properties and look at the ASP.NET tab. If 1.1 is selected, change it to 2.0 instead.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Simply delete the section declaration and add an "providerName=System.Data.SqlClient" (for instance) attribute

Answer (score 0):

Does your web.config contain at  tag?  Is there a  tag in it?  If so, the following might work for you: http://foxsys.blogspot.com/2009/05/iis7-errorgotcha-webconfig.html